# How to avoid if else statements in filter API in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, rest, .net-core

I have just started developing REST APIs in Net Core. I have to create an API for filter. 
For Example,

There are three tables, tbl_agent ,tbl_tags and tbl_agent_tags_mapping

Agent table has following Columns
id,
name,
company_name

Tags table has following Columns 
id, 
tag_name

tbl_agent_tags_mapping has following Columns 
id,
agent_id (FK),
tag_id (FK)

- Multiple tags can be assigned to agent

To filter Agent according to tag and name I am using below code which id not feasible.

```
IQueryable<tbl_agent> query = context.tbl_agent;

if (name != String.Empty)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.name == name);
}

if (tags.Count > 0)
{
    var agent_ids = context.tbl_agent_tags_mapping
            .Where(x => tags.Contains(x.id))
            .Select(x => x.id).ToList();

    query = query.Where(x => agent_ids.Contains(x.job_order_id));
}

List<tbl_agent> agent_list = query.ToList();
```

In this example, I have taken only two parameters but actually I have 10 to 12 params in POST request of Filter API.

Is there any design pattern to overcome this repetitive If..Else.. Statement?

Comment: You can write your own linq expression

Answer (score 1):

Me personally I don't know of any design pattern for this but I have come to the same issue and something to improve (a little bit and in some cases) was using this Extension Method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Func<bool> validation)
{
    return validation?.Invoke() == true ? query.Where(predicate) : query;
}
```

that way I can line up conditions like this:

```
var filtered = query.WhereIf(x => x.name == name, () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                    .WhereIf(x => agent_ids.Contains(x.job_order_id), () => tags.Any()) //.Count > 0
                    .WhereIf(x => x.AnotherProperty == anotherValue, () => AnotherCondition);
```

Of course, there will definitely be many other options, use the one that better suits your needs.

Hope this helps.-

Note: I would not advise you to remove the one related to the tags.Count > 0 (you can you tags.Any() btw) since this one is preventing hitting the database which otherwise you will be triggering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following;

```
if (tags.Count > 0) // don't get rid of this as it is
{
    var agent_ids = context.tbl_agent_tags_mapping
            .Where(x => tags.Containd(x.id))
            .Select(x => x.id).ToList();
}
query = query.Where(x => (name == String.Empty ||x.name == name) 
    && (tags.Count == 0 || agent_ids.Contains(x.job_order_id)));
```

I would not suggest to get rid of this condition. It prevents unnecessary db roundtrip.

Comment: i think the condition of ``name`` should be : ``string.IsnullOrEmpty(name)``? or ``&&`` instead ``||``

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any design pattern to overcome this repetitive If..Else.. Statement?

No.  Not really.  You don't want to embed the `name != String.Empty` or `tags.Count > 0` in the query itself, as one of the other current answers suggest.  That will result in a SQL Query that has predicates like

```
where @name <> '' or name = @name
  and @otherParam is null or otherCol = @otherParam
. . .
```

Which is a well-known anti-pattern for dynamic searching in SQL.  See eg [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).  As the query execution plan for the query will typically have to be the same for all parameter values, and so plan couldn't use any indexes on your searched columns.

You're doing the right thing, adding only those predicates that the user as requested.  @pinedax's extension method makes this pattern a bit cleaner.